# Will it be okay to use Amazon Glacier for everyday data retrieval?

Tags: cloud-computing

I am planning to use cloud storage for my app.  What my app will do is retrieval of users data and user authentication and have the ability to sync data continuously.

Is it a good idea to use Amazon Glacier?  Is there a bandwidth limitation or request or any downside of using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use case you describe sounds like a better fit for Amazon S3. Amazon Glacier is designed for long term archives, rarely read and not required immediately.

Comment: @michaelOn Amazon S3 if I have a 1000 devices that uses my apps will it cost me much even I optimized my request?

Comment: @mocca You should have a look at the pricing calculator http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html but I don't think it would cost you much unless you transfer a massive amount of data

Answer (score 8):

Glacier is an archiving service.  According to their site "Amazon Glacier is optimized for data that is infrequently accessed and for which retrieval times of several hours are suitable".  It's meant for data that you don't want to throw away but don't need to access regularly.

To draw a metaphor with paper documents.  If the paper on your desk is RAM, the filing cabinet in your office is your HDD, the departmental records room is Amazon S3, the offsite record archival that takes a week to requisition a box of files is Glacier.

Comment: Nice analogy...